# How to share Minikube instance on both Docker for Windows and WSL2?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

## How to share a Minikube instance amongst Windows/Windows WSL?

In Windows WSL `minikube start` fails:

```
  minikube v1.22.0 on Ubuntu 20.04
✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
  Updating the running docker "minikube" container ...
  StartHost failed, but will try again: provision: Temporary Error: NewSession: new client: new client: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
  Updating the running docker "minikube" container ...
  Failed to start docker container. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: provision: Temporary Error: NewSession: new client: new client: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain

❌  Exiting due to IF_SSH_AUTH: Failed to start host: provision: Temporary Error: NewSession: new client: new client: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
  Suggestion: Your host is failing to route packets to the minikube VM. If you have VPN software, try turning it off or configuring it so that it does not re-route traffic to the VM IP. If not, check your VM environment routing options.
  Documentation: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/vpn_and_proxy/
  Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3930
```

The above works in `Windows`:

```
  minikube v1.17.1 on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.19042 Build 19042
  minikube 1.22.0 is available! Download it: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v1.22.0
  To disable this notice, run: 'minikube config set WantUpdateNotification false'

✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Updating the running docker "minikube" container ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.20.2 on Docker 20.10.2 ...
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, dashboard, default-storageclass
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
```

Questions:

- Why would it fail on Linux? Note: I originally installed Minikube on Windows.
- Is there a way to share the Minikube environment?

#### Second I want to share one Docker context. `docker context ls`:

Windows:
Returns:

```
NAME                TYPE                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                             KUBERNETES ENDPOINT                 ORCHESTRATOR
default *           moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine              https://127.0.0.1:53873 (default)   swarm
desktop-linux       moby                                                          npipe:////./pipe/dockerDesktopLinuxEngine
```

Windows WSL (Ubuntu):

```
docker context ls
NAME                TYPE                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                             KUBERNETES ENDPOINT                 ORCHESTRATOR
default *           moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                 https://127.0.0.1:51967 (default)   swarm
desktop-linux       moby
```

Questions:

- What is default?
- What is desktop-linux?
- Which one is recommended to fully utilize the performance boost of WSL?

#### Third I want to share one Kubernetes context. `kubectl config get-contexts`:

Windows:

```
CURRENT   NAME                                       CLUSTER          AUTHINFO                        NAMESPACE
          docker-desktop                             docker-desktop   docker-desktop
          kubernetes/REDACTED   kubernetes       REDACTED
*         minikube                                   minikube         minikube                        default
```

Windows WSL (Ubuntu):

```
CURRENT   NAME             CLUSTER          AUTHINFO         NAMESPACE
          docker-desktop   docker-desktop   docker-desktop
*         minikube         minikube         minikube
```

Questions:

- What is `docker-desktop`?
- Can I safely delete `docker-desktop`?

Comment: Are you using [WSL 1 or WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions)?

Comment: It is WSL 2....

Comment: Which exactly command did you used to start minikube on WSL? Please check [this article](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/05/21/wsl-docker-kubernetes-on-the-windows-desktop/#minikube-kubernetes-from-everywhere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to synchronize both Windows/WSL by copying the configuration files:

```sh
mkdir ~/.kube \ && cp /mnt/c/Users/[USERNAME]/.kube/config ~/.kube
kubectl config use-context docker-for-desktop # Select the Windows context
kubectl cluster-info # Check if it works## Heading ##
```

Ref: https://devkimchi.com/2018/06/05/running-kubernetes-on-wsl/